# How do you play the triplets in Chopin's prelude no 4 in e minor?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I'm learning Chopin's prelude no 4 in e minor and have a question about the sheet music:

[image: sheet music for refrence]

In the first and seventh measure in the picture, there is a 3 under the c and e respectively. Previously I didn't know what they were, but it is now my understanding that they signify triplets.

So my questions are: what notes are included in the triplets, and how would I play them (rhythm wise)?